# Does the Observable operator takeUntil() depend upon it's order in pipe()

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Is the operator [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) affected by other operators, and do you have to use it twice inside a [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)?

For example;

Assume that I have an observable that emits a value when I no longer want to subscribe, and we'll refer to this as `this._destroyed`.

Does it matter if there is a [delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html) operator before a takeUntil?

```
 of("something").pipe(
      delay(1000),
      takeUntil(this._destroyed)
 );
```

Is the above any different from reversing the order?

```
 of("something").pipe(
      takeUntil(this._destroyed),
      delay(1000)
 );
```

What if I use `switchMap` do I have to call `takeUntil` twice?

```
 of("something").pipe(
      takeUntil(this._destroyed),
      delay(1000),
      switchMap(() => {
          return of("other").pipe(
             takeUntil(this._destroyed),
             delay(1000)
          );
      }
 );
```

Is the above functionally the same as calling `takeUntil` once?

```
 of("something").pipe(
      delay(1000),
      switchMap(() => {
          return of("other").pipe(delay(1000));
      }),
      takeUntil(this._destroyed)
 );
```

I guess I'm confused as to what happens when `takeUntil` is triggered and stops the current subscription. How is it impacted by when it is called in the pipe order (if there is any impact at all).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My understanding is that generally `takeUntil` should be the last operator in a chain because it can result in leaks. This article describes the issue: https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/

The article uses the following example:

```
import { combineLatest, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

declare const a: Observable<number>;
declare const b: Observable<number>;
declare const notifier: Observable<any>;

const c = a.pipe(
  takeUntil(notifier),
  o => combineLatest(o, b)
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

From the article:

> When the notifier emits, the observable returned by the takeUntil operator completes, automatically unsubscribing any subscribers.
>
> However, the subscriber to c is not subscribed to the observable returned by takeUntil — it’s subscribed to the observable returned by combineLatest — so it’s not automatically unsubscribed upon the takeUntil observable’s completion.
>
> The subscriber to c will remain subscribed until all of the observables passed to combinedLast complete. So, unless b completed before the notifier emitted, the subscription to b would leak.

While this post specifically refers to `switchMap`, I suspect the logic is the same. It may be less of an issue with `switchMap`, as there is only one inner observable.